# How do I define a new word.range through existing word.range without affecting the original?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following sub accepts a `word.range` as argument and formats it's text bold when embraced into double asterics `**`

```
Private Sub parse(parseRange As Word.Range)

'technical range for starting double asterics
Dim workRange As Word.Range
'range for enclosing doulbe asterics
Dim workRange2 As Word.Range
'another range for a bold text
Dim workRange3 As Word.Range
'flag variable 
Dim isSelect As Boolean
'number of iterated character in parseRange
Dim char

'I set my ranges through parseRange, otherwise I get "object variable not set" error
Set workRange = parseRange
Set workRange2 = parseRange
Set workRange3 = parseRange
        

char = 2
isSelect = False
Do While char <= parseRange.Characters.Count
    If parseRange.Characters(char) = "*" And parseRange.Characters(char - 1) = "*" Then
    Select Case isSelect
    Case False
        isSelect = True
        
        workRange.Start = parseRange.Start + char - 2

        'at this line the initial parseRange.characters.count is set to 2 and all the following code fails as a result.
        workRange.End = parseRange.Start + char
        workRange.Text = ""
    Case True
        isSelect = False
        workRange2.Start = parseRange.Start + char - 2
        workRange2.End = parseRange.Start + char
        workRange2.Text = ""
        
        workRange3.SetRange Start:=workRange.End, _
        End:=workRange2.Start
        workRange3.End = workRange2.Start
        workRange3.Bold = True
    End Select
    End If
    char = char + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

As I understand, because I defined workRange/2/3 through parseRange, the changes in these ranges are now affecting the original. How can I avoid such mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Word object model includes a [`Duplicate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.duplicate?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm157155334);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method for the `Range` object. This enables you to work with a copy of the range without affecting the start and end points of the original. Is that what you want?

```
Set workRange = parseRange.Duplicate
Set workRange2 = parseRange.Duplicate
Set workRange3 = parseRange.Duplicate
```